# How to bound the minimum singular value of a rectangular matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, svd

I have a map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}^m$ where $n<m$. Let $D_f\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ denote the Jacobian matrix.  I want to bound the smallest singular value of $J_f$ from above, for example $\sigma_{\text{min}}\left(J_f\right)\geq C$. Therefore I have

\begin{align}
\sigma_{\text{min}}\left(J_f\right)^2=&\min_{\mathbf{v}=1}\lVert J_f\cdot\mathbf{v}\rVert_2^2.\\
\end{align}

I wanted to try bound using inequality manipulations as the Jacobian is non-square so I didn't want to use the spectral matrix norm of $J_f^\dagger$. What inequality could I use from here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I remember on MATLAB there's a command that gives a lower bound to the condition number for very large systems of lin eq